# Re-rendering layout without render of child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With a code such as

```
<Layout pageName={pageName} rightMenu={rightMenu}>
  <OrganizationDashboardMembersMetrics
    layoutCallback={layoutCallback}
  />
</Layout>
```

- Page name is a simple string showing the page name within the layout
- Right menu is a JSX.Element having multiple buttons on the right side of the layout

Currently, I've got the following to implement the callback

```
const [pageName, setPageName] = useState<string>("");
const [rightMenu, setRightMenu] = useState<JSX.Element>(<></>);

const layoutCallback = useCallback(
  ({ pageName = "", rightMenu = <></> }) => {
    setPageName(pageName);
    setRightMenu(rightMenu);
  },
  [pageName, rightMenu]
);
```

But I tried to use simple function callback, or even to strip the callback itself and using the `setPageName` and `setRightMenu` directly from the child component. One detail that may be useful is I use `useQuery` (Apollo) and need the API data to set those data in the layout; it's dynamic.

It looks like this inside the child component

```
const pageName: string = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
const rightMenu: JSX.Element = (
  <React.Fragment>
   <IconButton
     color="inherit"
     aria-label="Employee metrics & reports"
     onClick={() => {
       window.location.assign(
         `/organization/dashboard/members/${id}/metrics`
       );
      }}
    >
    <BarChartIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </React.Fragment>
);

layoutCallback({ pageName, rightMenu });
```

Nothing seems to work, it re-render infinitely the child component whatever strategy I use. How would you approach this issue? I want to have a layout that gets data loaded from a child component without any need for re-rendering the child itself.

Also, I noticed that when using simple text (layout name) it doesn't reload infinitely, but once I have JSX.Element involved (right menu) it breaks.

Comment: You can remove `pageName` and `rightMenu` from `layoutCallback`'s dependency array, it does not use them.

Comment: Then you could wrap the child component in `React.memo` to prevent re-rendering if the props didn't change, or move the call of `layoutCallback` into an Effect that doesn't run on every rerender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go on and build a simple event bus with `rxjs` and communicate between components with it. For people facing the same problem, my implementation layer is pretty straight forward

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
export const eventBus = new Subject();

interface Event {
  type: string;
  payload: any;
}

export function eventBusEmit(event: Event): void {
  eventBus.next(event);
}

export function eventBusReceive(
  type: string,
  callback: (payload) => void
): void {
  eventBus.subscribe((event: any) => {
    if (event.type === type) return callback(event.payload);
  });
}
```

Then you can just emit and receive

```
eventBusEmit({ type: "page-name", payload: pageName });
eventBusReceive("page-name", (payload) => {
  setPageName(payload);
});
```

It avoids re-render between the two components because the dependency isn't direct.